# Testing key presses in Android app using Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, robolectric

I am testing a Fragment in my app which contains several AutoCompleteTextViews and EditTexts. I want to test entering data into these fields and pressing the Enter key to move to the next field. Is it possible to do this with Robolectric as unit tests? Or do I have to do this with Espresso and instrumented tests?

Comment: Are you writing unit or bigger test? Is key `enter` handled by view or Fragment? Is it the code of your app or from the Android framework?

Comment: @EugenMartynov I think understanding the difference between unit and integration tests is part of my difficult here. I am currently considering this as a unit test, but perhaps I am mistaken.

Comment: @EugenMartynov The primary issue is that I am modifying the behavior of AutoCompleteTextView using an anonymous listener. Eventually, I will probably subclass it instead. I want to have some reliable tests before I do such refactoring.

Comment: So the code you're want to test is yours and not Android. Then I'm pretty sure you can write a Robolectric test for it. If you share the code I might help you if you struggle with it.

Comment: You can write bigger tests with Robolectric but it is not recommended since Robolectric quite often Android emulation and not real code

Comment: @EugenMartynov I will try to come up with a mcve over the next few days.